# Using Tab to select dialog buttons - works on one Mac but not another

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

So, using `Cmd` + `Option` + `Del`, you "permanently delete", i.e. circumvent the recycling bin.

On my old MacBook Pro (2018 model, currently runninv macOS 14.1.1), the `Cancel` was highlighted, so pressing **Tab** would move the highlight to the `Delete`, and subsequently pressing the **Spacebar** would then click `Delete`, thereby allowing permanent delete from Finder in less than a second using only keystrokes.

On a different MacBook Pro (2021 model, also running macOS 14.1.1), the `Cancel` button is not highlighted after `Cmd` + `Option` + `Del`, so a **Tab** no longer allows a keystroke click of the `Delete` button.

Any idea how I enable this?

Answer (score 1):

You need Full Keyboard Access switched on to enable the Tab between buttons.

This used to be under System prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts

[image]

but since Ventura has moved to System Settings > Accessibility > Keyboard

[image]

Blue highlight faked in Photoshop because it doesn't screencap.

Comment: That's it, thanks! It adds this huge annoying blue rectangle around ANY selected part of most apps now (at least as soon as you start using the keyboard). Can you disable that? I didn't see an option in the "Accessibility" -> "Keyboard" settings and it's probably going to be too annoying to keep "Full keyboard access" turned on (and I don't have this on my older MacBook with the same OS version).

Comment: Edit: Found it. Do NOT enable "Full keyboard access", but INSTEAD go to "Accessibility" -> "Keyboard" and click the "Keyboard Settings..." button.
In there, enable the "Keyboard Navigation". If enabled, without the "Full keyboard access", it behaves as expected. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Keyboard Navigation doesn't work for me on Ventura & didn't yet exist on Mojave [my earlier example].

Comment: No worries, you definitely led my down the right path, so thanks a lot!